# Logic Test to fins the True or false for set format

Tags: regex, google-sheets, boolean, logic, match

I need to write a logic test to one of my tasks I need to get True only Have Number like XX.YYYY.

- X - Need to be 8 (So then I need XX Only 88)
- Y - Need to be 0 to 9 and Only Exception is first Y can be C like C123 or C987
- Any Space also becomes False

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Obse0BsXnP6o3Tz8uEI7EL7ksOtHRi5SscGysscpGI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(B8:B19&"", "^88\.[0-9Cc]\d{3}$"))
```

[image]